# How to move div horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to the div box with image move left to right,

I tried another script: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/MzHmN/

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head></head>    
    <body style>
        <div id="slideleft" class="slide">
            <button>slide it</button>
            <div class="inner">Slide to the left</div>
            <div style="width:50px; height:50px">
                <img src="sceen.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide .inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: -500px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#slideleft button').click(function () {
         var $lefty = $(this).next();
         $lefty.animate({
             left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: With CSS? There is relative and absolute positioning.. You can also use padding/margins to manipulate the element.

Comment: when are you trying to move the div box from left to right? on button click? and which div you are referring to? take some time to explain it clearly.

Comment: css code here:  <style>
    .slide {
      position: relative;
      background-color: gray;
      height: 100px;
      width: 500px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slide .inner {
      position: absolute;
      left: -500px;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color:#e3e3e3;
      height: 30px;
      width: 500px;
    }
    </style>

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
            var $lefty = $(this).next();
            $lefty.animate({
              left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
                -$lefty.outerWidth() :
                0
            });
          });
        });
    </script>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CSS:

```
div.inner{
background:black;
margin-left:0;
width:100px;
animation:sample 2s;
-webkit-animation:sample 2s;
}
keyframes sample{
from{margin-left:100%;}
to{margin-left:0%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sample{
from{margin-left:100%;}
to{margin-left:0%;}
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apRMU/17/

Comment: Hi Naiz, i tried following script, i'm trying to move horizontally with image http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/MzHmN/

Comment: do you want to move image automatically?

Comment: when we click one the plus button, div expand horizontally with image  and minus button display, then collapse div and only show image with plus button. thanks.

Comment: hi Nariz, thank you so much. but i need to show image without mouse over, when we mouse over div and image going like as your code. thanks. i need to show horizontally 3 images, is it possible.. thanks

Comment: try to make the width of div > div to 120px;

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply width to main container. Please replace it with below line and check in your browser.

```
 <div id="slideleft" class="slide" style="width:100px; margin:0 auto">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Floradu88: Pritesh Gajjar simply didn't format the "below line" properly, so it was hidden in the text.

Answer (score 0):

use margin for outer space and padding for inner space
try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body style>
    <div id="slideleft" class="slide">
        <button>slide it</button>
        <div class="inner">Slide to the left</div>
        <div style="width:50px; height:50px; margin-left: 100px;"><img src="sceen.jpg">
       </div>         
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the following link to watch live demo... [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/KaTNH/)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Animation test</title>
<style>

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=500"}, 2000);
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 1000);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:relative">
    <div id="b" style="position:absolute;">B</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```